# HTML Vertically Centered Button Alignment

Tags: html, button, alignment

How do I align a button on the right of 2 textboxes, but vertically in the middle? (I'm going for a Windows 8 Metro feel.)

What I have:

[image]

What I want (mockup):

[image]

Comment: Windows 8 style = button with solid color no border.

Comment: Why not just give it a margin-top?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work as it's not in it's own column.

Comment: Also: http://www.winsupersite.com/content/content/142376/refresh_04.jpg see?

Comment: Put it in it's own column.  Surround the text boxes in a div, float them left.  Surround the button in a div, float it left.  Set widths for everything.

Comment: The sign up thing is its own div. Doing float left makes everything screwed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Table tag as follows

```
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="textbox1">
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="textbox2">
      </td>
      <td>
      <button name="abc" value="Submit"   type="button">Submit</button>
      </td>
     <tr>
    </table>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Never use tables for aligning elements on a page.  Tables are for tabular data.

Comment: it is a simplest way. I think :)

Comment: Probably going to use this method, but wondering if it's "taboo" to use tables this way?